# World of Zuul: non-static method getCurrentRoom() cannot be referenced from a static context

Tags: java, bluej

I know this question comes up often, but even after looking at asked question's I can't find a solution..

So for school we have to create an own version of World of Zuul. I've implemented a beamer in it. First I put it in the Game class, but I decided it would be better to have it in it's own class, Beamer. The Beamer class looks as follows:

```
public class Beamer
{
    private Room beamerRoom;
    private Room beamer;
    private int timesFired;
    private boolean beamerCharged;

    public Beamer(int timesFired, boolean beamerCharged)
    {
        this.timesFired = 0;
        this.beamerCharged = false;
    }

    public int getTimesFired()
    {
        return timesFired;
    }

    public Room getBeamerRoom()
    {
        return beamerRoom;
    }

    public boolean getBeamerCharged()
    {
        return beamerCharged;
    }

    public Room setBeamerRoom(Room room)
    {
        this.beamerRoom = Game.getCurrentRoom();
        return beamerRoom;
    }

    /**
     * Try to use beamer device. When you charge the beamer, it memorizes the current     room.
     * When you fire the beamer, it transports you immediately back to the room it was
     * charged in.
     */
    public void beamer(Command command){
        if (!command.hasSecondWord()) {
            // if there is no second word, we don't know what to do...
            System.out.println("Charge or fire beamer?");
            return;
        }
        String action = command.getSecondWord();

        if (action.equals("charge")) {
            if(timesFired() < 1)
            {
                beamerRoom = Game.getCurrentRoom();
                System.out.println("This room is charged to beam!");
                beamerCharged = true;
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The beamer has already been fired and can't be charged again");
            }
        } else if (action.equals("fire")) {
            if(beamerCharged == true)
            {    
                if(timesFired < 1)
                {
                    Game.getCurrentRoom() = beamer.getBeamerRoom();
                    System.out.println("The beamer has succesfully been fired!");
                    System.out.println(currentRoom.getLongDescription());
                    timesFired++;
                    beamerCharged = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    System.out.println("You can only fire the beamer once!");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("The beamer hasn't been charged yet!");
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("Invalid beamer command!");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

I get the error `method getCurrentRoom() cannot be referenced from a static context` here:
`beamerRoom = Game.getCurrentRoom();`

The method in Game to get the current room is as follows:

```
public Room getCurrentRoom()
    {
        return currentRoom;
    }
```

Very simple, which in my mind should work.

How can I solve this issue? I've looked around but can't find a fix that works..

If you need more of the Game class code, please ask. I didn't post it here since it's 300+ lines.

EDIT:
I already found what I did wrong. By using `Game.getCurrentRoom` it looked at the class Game, rather than an object of the Game. At least that's what I think went wrong. I had the error message with more methods, using capital letters (`Game.<method>`), `Player.<method>`), but when I didn't use the capital letters (`game.<method>`), `player.<method>`) it worked fine.

So I guess the problem is solved.

Comment: If you believe it should work, you need to go back to the other questions to understand why it doesn't. How much do you understand about what `static` means? Given that each `Game` instance can have a different "current room", *which* `Game`'s current room are you trying to use?

Answer (score 0):

When you call `Game.getCurrentRoom()` you arer trying to call the method on the class `Game`. But you defined the method as an instance method. So you either need to change your code to use a singleton instane of Game to access its instance methods, or you need to declare the mehtods on Class as static. Note that those methods again can only access class members, not instance members.

```
public static Room getCurrentRoom()
{
    return currentRoom; // currentRoom has to be declared as a private static class member
}
```